# Is there a way to combine two jenkins job results ?

Tags: jenkins

I am looking for something (script/plugin/hack) to combine two jenkins job results.

the reason I need this is, when I run first job only one test fails out of 100. I re-run that one in a different job and it passed. now I want to just combine it.

I want to combine it once results have been already published and job is completely done. I am not looking for an option that helps me before job is done, like something during "post-build" etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're using, but I had a similar problem with rpsec where one spec would fail the first time I ran it and would pass the second time I ran it. If you're experiencing the same thing, you could simply run the test independently in the same job with `|| true` so it doesn't fail the job and then go on to run the rest. 

I know you said you wanted something for after the fact instead of during the job, but this is how I solved it personally.

Comment: Thanks Jacob for your response. I am using "execute shell-script" to exeute robot framework test suite. your suggestion would help when there is no change required but what if you need to change a minor thing and then you want to re-run just the failed case. That's when most of my trouble starts. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm ignorant to your process, so I'll ask this: Why would you have to change something (minor or major) and then run the failed case? Isn't the purpose of running test cases so that you can verify the code is performing correctly without any modification? If your tests are sequential (one creates data in a database, the next verifies the data is there or something like that), that's another story. It's probably bad design, but it has a purpose.

Can you explain what the purpose of the "minor" change is so I can maybe be more helpful?

Comment: Yes Jacob, you are right. the purpose of running test cases is to verify the code. But what if its a minor setup issue or automation script issue or just a timing issue and want to re-run after increasing a little time. So not changing anything in the actual code under test but changing something else. Sorry, I wasn't clear enough before.